# R2dbcRepository Return Nothing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I'm trying to get data from my `UserRepository` that extends `R2dbcRepository` like the code below

```
public interface UserRepository extends R2dbcRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
    Mono<UserEntity> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

this repository works fine on saving `UserEntity` instance but it doent't work when I call `findByEmail` method. I wrote a test with `log()` before subscribe to debug like the code below:

```
@Test
void test2(){
    this.userRepository.findByEmail("example@email.com").log().subscribe();
}
```

But on the console, the it doesn't show the `onComplete` or even `onNext` like a normal publisher should. instead, it only shows this message:

```
[main] reactor.Mono.Next.1 : onSubscribe(MonoNext.NextSubscriber)
[main] reactor.Mono.Next.1 : request(unbounded)
```

and of course, I have data in my database that has that email name:
[image: table]

Is there any step I miss? Thanks!

Comment: How’s your entity looks like?